# leaflet Map only having correct position after browser resize

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

first I want to show you a screenshot what my issue is, I think it makes it easier to understand
https://i.gyazo.com/05f4d98fd68d9802264a9f016ba05cc6.png

As you can see in the image, there is a gap between my left navbar, which is expandable, and the left border of my map image

However, once I drag and drop the whole browser, so its window will get resized, the gap is gone
https://i.gyazo.com/d76dbfe1a3bb30d73a48697616520403.png

The gray line next to the navbar is the left side of the map image I use.
Some other Information:
Using Leaflet.css and .js 1.9.3
Using bootsrap5
Using jQuery.3.6.3
Using Windows machine with Xampp to test

I am in despair since I can not figure out what the issue is, I tried changing some CSS
for example giving the `#map` container `left: -112px;` or changing the `.leaflet-map-pane` `translate3d` numbers, however, I just can not figure it out for some reason.

Here is the Code I use, I broke it to down have minimal reproduction steps possible, I was hoping if someone knew why this would happen or what can cause it

jQuery and JS - It is included in the HTML, put I post it separate as well

```
<script>
    $groesse = 6048;
    // Create a new Leaflet map object
    var map = L.map("map", {
      crs: L.CRS.Simple
    });
    var bounds = L.latLngBounds([
      [0, 0],
      [$groesse, $groesse]
    ]);
    var wantedZoom = map.getBoundsZoom(bounds, true);
    var center = bounds.getCenter();
    map.setView(center, wantedZoom);
    map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
    // Set maximum and minimum zoom levels
    map.setMaxZoom(2);
    map.setMinZoom(-4);
    map.setZoom(-3)
    L.imageOverlay("", bounds, {}).addTo(map);
  </script>
  <script>
      function toggleFilters() {
      $('#navbar_right').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
      }, function() {});
    }

    //     // Get the toggle button and navbar_right element
    const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-toggle-filters');
    const navbarRight = document.querySelector('.navbar_right');

    // Add click event listener to the toggle button
    toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // Toggle the collapsed class of the navbar_right element
      navbarRight.classList.toggle('collapsed');
    });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="./jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" /> 
</head>
<body>

  <div id="content" style="float:left">
    <div class="navbar_left">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-white bg-dark" style="width: 14rem;height: 100%; border-right-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
        <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
          <img id="logo" class="logo" src="" width="80%; height=auto; z-index: 10" />
        </a>
        <hr class="style-two">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light hideall" id="hideall" style="border-radius: 0px;margin: 0.3rem;">Hide all</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light showall" id="showall" style="border-radius: 0px;margin: 0.3rem;">Show all</a>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <li>
            <a id="mapfliter" href="#" class="nav-link text-white btn-toggle-filters" onclick="toggleFilters()">
              <img src="" style="width: 12%;height: auto;vertical-align: sub;">
              <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
                <use xlink:href="#speedometer2"></use>
              </svg>
              Map Filter
            </a>
          </li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form autocomplete="off">
      <div class="navbar_right" id="navbar_right">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-white bg-dark" style="width: 14rem; height: 100%; border-right-style: solid; border-width: 1px;padding:0px!important;">
          
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="map" style="background-image: url('');  background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-attachment: fixed;  background-size: cover;">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $groesse = 6048;
    // Create a new Leaflet map object
    var map = L.map("map", {
      crs: L.CRS.Simple
    });
    var bounds = L.latLngBounds([
      [0, 0],
      [$groesse, $groesse]
    ]);
    var wantedZoom = map.getBoundsZoom(bounds, true);
    var center = bounds.getCenter();
    map.setView(center, wantedZoom);
    map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
    // Set maximum and minimum zoom levels
    map.setMaxZoom(2);
    map.setMinZoom(-4);
    map.setZoom(-3)
    L.imageOverlay("", bounds, {}).addTo(map);
  </script>
  <script>
      function toggleFilters() {
      $('#navbar_right').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
      }, function() {});
    }
    //     // Get the toggle button and navbar_right element
    const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-toggle-filters');
    const navbarRight = document.querySelector('.navbar_right');

    // Add click event listener to the toggle button
    toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // Toggle the collapsed class of the navbar_right element
      navbarRight.classList.toggle('collapsed');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.leaflet-container {
  background-color: black;
}
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
  display: none;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background-color: #212225;
}


#content {
  flex: 1 1;
  order: 2;
  display: flex;
}
#map {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: max-content;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
}

.navbar_right {
  flex-basis: fit-content;
  background-color: #212225;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
.navbar_right::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.navbar_right li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(81, 81, 81) !important;
  color: white !important;
}
.navbar_right li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar_right ul li {
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.navbar_right input {
  margin-left: 10px;
  align-items: baseline;
}
.form-check-input {
  float: right !important;
}

.navbar_left {
  flex-basis: fit-content;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh !important;
}


.bg-dark {
  background-color: rgb(33, 34, 37) !important;
}

li {
  height: 2.5rem;
}

#showImage:checked + label .image-overlay {
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar_left {
  float: left;
}
.navbar_right {
  float: right;
  display:none;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    right: -200px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is your style for

```
 #map {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: max-content;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
}
```

flex:1 already covers flex-grow you did later. margin-left and right auto for what?
There are many confusing styles in the whole css section.
If it is a simple equal size divs, you are trying to create. Then just give the parent div display:flex and the child divs flex:1 in css. Since you are using bootstrap, you can use their grid system for finer controls on the size. Those flex-basis styles are confusing as well if you are trying your nav div to grow. Also inspect the site on browser for that gap you are trying to fix. If you can upload it to github and generate a live site link. I can take a look at it.